# RT Patch on Raspberry pi 4 running ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, raspberrypi, realtime

So I've been using ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a raspberry pi 4 with 4GB RAM. I've found multiple articles explaining how install a preempt rt patch on AMD based systems but have been unable to so on my raspi. Has anyone been successful in doing so yet? (Note that I don't want to use raspbian)